# max product of 5 distinct-digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I ran into the following problem my computer solved, but I can't seem
to rigorously prove it is correct:

**What two 5 distinct digit numbers give the maximal product?**

I know the solution is `96420 * 87531`, but how can I prove it is indeed maximal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Greedy theorem, assign the highest power of $10$ to Your highest digits.

$9$ and $8$ are going to be the first digit

$7$ and $6$ are going to be the second digit

.
.
.

$1$ and $0$ are going to be the fifth digit.

Now, notice that no matter how You arrange the digits between the two numbers, their sum is always the same.

Product of two numbers with constant sum is maximized if their difference is minimized.

The difference is minimized if the numbers are $96420$ and $87531$.

Answer (score 1):

To get trivialities out of the way:

- Both five digit-numbers have descending order
- $9$ and $8$ are the only valid choices for the first digits of the first and second number, because $9 \cdot 8 \geq n \cdot m$ for any $n, m \in 1 \ldots 9, n\neq m$.

Now again, we can fairly easily deduce that $7$ and $6$ are the second digits, as $97\cdot 86$ and $96 \cdot 87$ are larger than what any other choice for second digits yields. The question is whether we should pick $(97 \ldots, 86 \ldots)$ or $(96 \ldots, 87 \ldots)$. It is the latter, as $96 \cdot 87 > 97 \cdot 86$.

Continue onwards ($964 \cdot 875 > 965 \cdot 874$ and so forth) to deduce the entire five-digit numbers.

Comment: Intuitively I agree, but here is something that bothered me: following the same reason, you could start from the right, choosing $30$ times $21$ which is the largest, continuing leftwards ... only this is incorrect ... **the greedy approach fails from the right**

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Yes, there seems to be something iffy with my answer. I'll leave it up as reference and think about it some more.

Comment: Suppose you swap the two xth-place digits, for example $98x \ldots$ and $76 y \ldots$ to $98y \ldots$ and $76x \ldots$. Then if $98y \cdot 76x   > 98x \cdot 76y $, it follows that $98y \ldots \cdot 76x \ldots  > 98x \ldots \cdot 76y \ldots$. Therefore, for the highest-product solution, no swaps which increase the product of the leading digits can be possible, which leaves little choice for the choice of digits i.e. only one of the two 'distributions' for every pair out of $(9,8)$, $(7,6)$, $\ldots$ is possible.